# Sitecore FakeDB Deserialisation and Unicorn

Tags: unicorn, unit-testing, fakedb

Using Sitecore 9.0.1, Im looking at using Sitecore Fake DB for unit testing.

Im interested in using the Deserialisation extension so that I can test using content that's been serialised to disk

https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/FakeDb-Serialization

Has anyone had any success doing this with Unicorn .yml serialised items? Or is it TDS only?

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to be TDS. You can use items that you have serialized in Sitecore. Go to the Developer Toolbar, and then click on Serialize Item / Serialize Tree.